# Push Commit origin:master with git (android studio)

Tags: android, git

I've inserted an image in drawable and tried to push. Got a IDE error. Tried to push again and I got this next time when I'm trying to push.
Can you please help? I'm new to VCS.[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Consider learning got outside of an IDE?

Comment: Maybe help us out and tell us what error you received?

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the mistake I've committed so that I can work on that? @evolutionxbox

Comment: Honestly I don’t understand the issue.

Comment: At least tell me in which situation these extra nodes appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better try in your studio terminal

1- **git add .**

2- **git commit -m "your message here"**

3- **git push origin master**

done.

check **git status**

Comment: did you write with dot "git add ."

Comment: **git push origin**

This sloved my problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: remote: Repository not found.
this is my error